# convert win32 console application to windows form application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to make windows form this is the Form1.h:

```
#pragma once

#include"student.h"

namespace formApp {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;    

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(529, 209);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"max";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(262, 76);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(262, 132);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(262, 181);
        this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
        this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox3->TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // textBox4
        // 
        this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(262, 37);
        this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
        this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox4->TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // textBox5
        // 
        this->textBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(529, 256);
        this->textBox5->Name = L"textBox5";
        this->textBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox5->TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(206, 36);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(15, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 6;
        this->label1->Text = L"id";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(198, 80);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(36, 13);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 7;
        this->label2->Text = L"mark1";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this->label3->AutoSize = true;
        this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(209, 135);
        this->label3->Name = L"label3";
        this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(36, 13);
        this->label3->TabIndex = 8;
        this->label3->Text = L"mark2";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this->label4->AutoSize = true;
        this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(201, 181);
        this->label4->Name = L"label4";
        this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(36, 13);
        this->label4->TabIndex = 9;
        this->label4->Text = L"mark3";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(745, 290);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
    student s;
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             
             int id= System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
               int g1= System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
               int g2= System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
               int g3= System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox4->Text);
         s.setStudent(id,g1,g2,g3);

         textBox5->Text=  System::Convert::ToString(s.maxGrade());




         }
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
};
}
```

and on Header Files I have added header file student.h and wrote class student in it :
student.h :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class student
{
int id;
int grade1,grade2,grade3;

public:

student()
{




}


void setStudent(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
     id=a;
    grade1=b;
    grade2=c;
    grade3=d;


}


int maxGrade()
{
  int max=grade1;
  if(grade2>max)
    max=grade2;

  if(grade3>max)
  {
     max=grade3;
  
  }


  return max;




}



 };
```

But the compiler gave me errors:

> Error  3   error C2662: 'student::maxGrade' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'student' to 'student &'
>
> Error  2   error C2662: 'student::setStudent' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'student' to 'student &'
>
> Error  1   error C4368: cannot define 's' as a member of managed 'formApp::Form1': mixed types are not supported

please can you tell me the correct way to add student class to the windows form application and use it .

Answer (score 0):

As you have it defined now, `student` is an unmanaged class, and `Form1` is a managed class. Managed classes are not allowed to have unmanaged classes as inline fields. You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Make `s` a pointer type (`student*`) instead, and create a new object in the Form1's constructor.
2. (Preferred) Change `student` to be a managed class as well (`ref class student`), and make `s` a managed handle (`student^`).

Now, that said, you're setting yourself up for lots of headaches if you try to write this in C++/CLI. Do consider switching to C#, it will make the WinForms development tons easier.